# c3p0 getNumBusyConnectionsDefaultUser()... What does busy mean?

Tags: c3p0

I know this is a very basic question, but I would like a deeper understanding of what "busy" means.  I have done a double check that I close all my connections.  I know that in c3p0, "the pool will intercept the call to close() and check the underlying Connection back into the pool."  I would expect the number of busy connections to trend to zero, but this does not happen.  Any ideas why?  How long does a connection stay in the "busy" state?  Shouldn't the connection become unbusy when I close it?  Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK...  I finally figured this out by watching the DEBUG log statements from mchange.  There is a "check for expired resources" every 5 seconds.  If you get and use a connection just before that window and then you call "getNumConnectionsDefaultUser()" within that window you may not get an accurate count because the connection could be marked s busy and become unbusy before the window closes.

Essentially (I think), c3p0 does not maintain its own counters based on a change in status, it cycles through the collection of connections every five seconds checking current status.

Comment: Our system makes some pretty heavy duty AJAX calls every ten seconds, so with multiple users many of the "closed" connections are within the five second window.

Comment: "Busy" Connections are those c3p0 is expecting to be checked back in (that haven't been excluded from the pool due to errors). The expiration check shouldn't really affect this; Connections aren't considered check-out or busy while they are checked. But in general, it's hard to hav very exact expectations about these counts. Nearly everything about c3p0 is asynchronronous, so when you `close()` a Connection it may not immediately stop being busy. Eventually it should, so if all Connections are closed and none reopened, busy Connections should trend toward zero.