# Detect connection leaks in pooled DataSource

Tags: connection-pooling, c3p0, connection-leaks

I am writing code in order to detect whether my application is leaking connections or not. I use `c3p0` as connection pool.

In my unit tests, I have tried to create a `@Rule` that checks, at the end of the tests, that there are no pending connections. This will help me find code that is forgetting to close `Connection`s. For now, this has to work with c3p0 pool.

I have written the following code:

```
public class ConnectionLeakChecker extends Verifier
{

    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void verify() throws Throwable
    {
        if (dataSource == null)
            return;

        if (dataSource instanceof PooledDataSource)
        {
            PooledDataSource pool = (PooledDataSource) dataSource;
            int numBusyConnectionsDefaultUser = pool.getNumBusyConnectionsDefaultUser();
            if (numBusyConnectionsDefaultUser > 0)
                throw new AssertionError("Connections not released: " + numBusyConnectionsDefaultUser);
        }
        else
            throw new AssertionError("Database pool type not supported: " + dataSource.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
}
```

However, when instantiating the component as @Rule, it will randomly detect one pending connections (in my current tests, I use only one).

Some tests will have a connection hanging, others not. If I run a failing test alone, I usually don't get any more complaints.

I think the `getNumBusyConnectionsDefaultUser()` method does not do what I would like to achieve.

Somebody help?

Comment: Putting a `sleep` in the checker code never leaves connections open. So, that's likely not the way to detect leaks

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49477567/2834978) related answer.